# rails controller design : listing and create on the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

starting from the rails blog tutorial, i want to have listing and create functionality on a single view. But i don't known how to design the controller to accomplish this.

The index view must show a simple list of posts and a form to create a new post.
Can i solve this with partials? How? I need a "new" and "create" methods? With only create is not enough?

```
class MyPostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the form in the `index` view, render the form. I'd *recommend* a partial, but it's not *mandatory*. Depending on the form implementation you may need a new `Post` model, that's as easy as putting a `@post = Post.new` in the `index` action.

The reason `create` *may* not be "enough" is because some forms are "for" an instance of the model. In those cases generally the `new` action makes a new `Post` and renders the form, whereas the `create` action actually saves (creates) it.

Comment: Thanks Dave, i misunderstand partials views. I supposed that each partial was a mvc itself and i could compose mvc's using partials.

Comment: @eze1981 A partial can't be an "MVC itself", a partial is just the V. The C sets up everything required for the V, regardless of what's contained in the V, but rendering a partial does just that--renders a partial, it won't make any C calls automatically.